# Unit tile swap. Works one way and not the other, Why?

Tags: civilization-5

When there are two of my units adjacent to each other, you can perform a unit swap between their two hex tiles. You do this by dragging the cursor of one unit over the other. The cursor turns white, let go of the mouse button and the units swap tiles.

I find that sometimes I select unit A and find that trying to swap with unit B does not work. However, switching to using unit B to initiate the swap does work. Why is this?

Comment: In my experience from playing the game, it depends on what the units are and what type of tiles they are on. It's not down as an answer cos i'm not 100% sure on that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally I find this when the target (the one I don't have selected) is fortified. When you select a fortified unit it is unfortified (at least in appearance/temporarily), so then you can swap it with the original unit.

Comment: ... or garrisoned.

Comment: Confirmed. I had two units fortified and nether of them wanted to hex swap!